# Firebase Database method "set" on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have database that i am trying to populate with variables from a Javascript website, to test it I wrote the following code.

Initializing code (all the variables are populated accordingly, taken from the Database API):

```
function Firebase(){
   var config = {
  apiKey: "(Key)",
  authDomain: "(Domain),
  databaseURL: "(URL)",
  projectId: "(ProjectID)",
  storageBucket: "(Bucket)",
  messagingSenderId: "(ID)"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

To set data I have the following code

```
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
rootRef.set({
  name: Kemper,
  }).then(success  => 
{  console.log('success',success);
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log('error',error);
              }
    );
```

Firebase() Will be initialized when the submit button is clicked, with the following code:

```
  <input type = "submit" onclick="Firebase()" action = "welcome.php" id="submit"></button>
```

The code does not show the success or error console.log, and I cannot find the issue with it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it possible to create a plunkr? Or how is the `.set` related to the `Firebase()` function?

Comment: I was wrong, the console reads the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Kemper is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to save a string as number.

The `.set()` call should look like this:

```
rootRef.set({
  name: "Kemper", // quotation marks added
})
```

Comment: That eliminated the error in the console log, thanks but it still is not setting the data in the actual database. It also is not showing success or error on the console log when hitting the submit button. I also should have included in the main code that I have                                                            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js"></script>  in my code. Is there any reasons why it is not setting the data to the database. Thousand thank yous.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr with your code? Otherwise it's hard for me to see how it works together.

Comment: Yeah https://plnkr.co/edit/qIYWAushNNhv2UU9oYAC?p=catalogue Most of the site is left unedited because I want to take care of this problem first

Comment: Make sure to add your script in the `<head>` or at the end of the`<body>`. The `<footer>` also belongs inside the `<body>`. These are just some semantic things, they haven't caused the error. I think error comes from the submit action on your form. I've modified your plunkr (add your firebase credentials and try it out): https://embed.plnkr.co/JuOzM0qwPiROseOykEMm/

Comment: Alright, thank you for showing me the correct syntax for HTML and Java Script, I was very confused on that. It works now, a thousand thank yous, why would you think the submit action was causing a problem? For learning experiences.

Comment: `<input type="submit">` causes a reload. So your page was reloaded immediately once you've clicked it and nothing happened. But if you really want a `<input type="submit">` there are a lot of workarounds to avoid the reload.